# BO Webi - Need Variable to Check if Two Fields Contain the Same Name

Tags: business-objects

I'm looking to create a variable that will compare two fields to see if they contain the same name. For example, If Performing Personnel = Second Nurse Witness for each Financial Number Then "Y" Else "N". I can't seem to get the correct syntax. Any suggestions would be a big help.
[Compare Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqVlG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your second object "Four Eyes Second Nurse Witness" or "Second Nurse Witness"? If it is the latter this should do it...

```
=If([Performing Personnel] = [Second Nurse Witness]; "Y"; "N")
```

If you prefer the If Then syntax it would look like this...

```
=If [Performing Personnel] = [Second Nurse Witness] Then
    "Y"
Else
    "N"
```

If it is possible to have spaces you may need to add a Trim() function around each object when comparing them.